# Getting errors on run command npm start in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, angular

I'm new to angular2 and trying to setup angularjs2.0 project on ubuntu. I installed `npm` in the root directory my angular2 app. But on `npm start` it gives error:

Here are the errors shown in npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.0
3 info using node@v0.10.44
4 verbose node symlink /usr/bin/node
5 verbose config Skipping project config: /home/kisuser/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
6 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from /home/kisuser/package.json
7 error install Couldn't read dependencies
8 verbose stack Error: ENOENT, open '/home/kisuser/package.json'
9 verbose cwd /home/kisuser/nimbldeck
10 error Linux 3.13.0-83-generic
11 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
12 error node v0.10.44
13 error npm  v2.15.0
14 error path /home/kisuser/package.json
15 error code ENOPACKAGEJSON
16 error errno 34
17 error package.json ENOENT, open '/home/kisuser/package.json'
17 error package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
17 error package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
18 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

I also have package.json file in the same directory:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-webpack-starter",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "description": "An Angular 2 Webpack Starter kit featuring Angular 2 (Router, Http, Forms, Services, Tests, E2E, Coverage), Karma, Protractor, Jasmine, Istanbul, TypeScript, and Webpack by AngularClass",
  "author": "Patrick Stapleton <patrick@angularclass.com>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "npm cache clean && rimraf node_modules doc typings coverage dist",
    "clean:dist": "rimraf dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "watch:dev": "webpack --watch --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch:prod": "webpack --watch --config webpack.prod.config.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:dev": "webpack --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "server": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached  --content-base src/",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --hot",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver:start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "lint": "tsconfig-lint",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "e2e:live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "test": "karma start",
    "ci": "npm run e2e && npm run test",
    "docs": "typedoc --options typedoc.json --exclude **/*.spec.ts ./src/",
    "start": "npm run server",
    "typings-install": "typings install",
    "postinstall": "npm run typings-install",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "angular2-moment": "^0.4.2",
    "clipboard": "^1.5.9",
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "es7-reflect-metadata": "^1.6.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.2",
    "ng2-cookies": "^0.1.4",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "es6-promise-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "faker": "^3.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.9.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "json-server": "^0.8.8",
    "karma": "^0.13.21",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^1.1.6",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
    "protractor": "^3.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-helper": "0.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "ts-node": "^0.5.5",
    "tsconfig-lint": "^0.6.0",
    "tslint": "^3.3.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.3.12",
    "typescript": "1.8.2",
    "typings": "^0.6.8",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-load-plugins": "^0.1.2",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-validator": "^1.0.0-beta.4"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a package.json file in order for npm to use. You need to create one with all the dependencies. Fix/Add the package.json to your root folder and you should be fine.

Here is a simple package.json :

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies":{}
}
```

Update:
I've cloned this project https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter.git and was able to install and start. The current version of the project is far more advanced and works like a charm. how about you try that ?

Comment: can you link github repo ?

Comment: did you npm install first ?

Comment: do you mean to share github repository with you?

Comment: Yes, I did install npm

Comment: No, my project is not at this repository.

Comment: @AmitThukral it is not an install of NPM, but go to the project, and run the 'npm install' to install all the dependencies of the project, as located in the package.json.  Your error though still indicates that the package.json is not found.